# How NSDictionary algorithm works in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, hash

I need to understand how `NSDictionary` algorithm works in iOS?

I am assuming it is using the hashing algorithm internally just like in Java `HashMap` uses concept of `bucket` and `hashcode`.

Are mechanism of NSDictionary is the same as that of `HashMap` in Java?

Comment: Please search Internet, there are tonns of tutorials about that topic.For [exmaple](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDictionary` uses `CFDictionary` which is open source by Apple [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFDictionary.c).

Also see [Let's Build NSMutableDictionary](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-03-16-lets-build-nsmutabledictionary.html) by Mike Ash.